# Bootstrap-Table Extension - Dropdown in Row Pops Under Table Container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using a bootstrap dropdown in each row of a table that uses the [bootstrap-table extension](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) written by wenzhixin. The dropdown itself works fine, however, when I open a dropdown near the bottom of the table it shows the vertical scrollbar and the options pop under the containing div for the table. I've been playing with the CSS for a while with no joy.

Has anyone ran into this issue and found a solution?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be slightly "hackish" but it's straightforward and simple. The extension creates the table with a `fixed-table-body` class. Once that's removed it renders without constraining bootstrap dropdowns.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    onPostBody: function(data) {
        $('#table')
            .find('.fixed-table-body')
            .removeClass('fixed-table-body');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well if you use the bootstrap-table-contextmenu extension
https://github.com/prograhammer/bootstrap-table-contextmenu

This to create the button That toggle the dropdown

```
<ul id="userstable-context-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-item="edit"><a>Edit</a></li>
    <li data-item="resetPwd"><a>Reset</a></li>
</ul
```

In you table you add :

```
<th class="editButton" data-field="editButton" data-formatter="editFormatter"></th>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $("#userstable").bootstrapTable({
        pagination: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageList: [10, 25, 50, 'All'],
        search: "true",
        showRefresh:"true",
        url: "api/users/{{user.userId}}/{{user.role}}",
        contextMenu: '#userstable-context-menu',
        contextMenuButton: '.userstable-button'
    });
})

$('#userstable').on('contextmenu-item.bs.table', function (e, row, $el) {
        if($el.data("item")== "edit"){
            var x = "do something";
        }
}

function editFormatter(value, row, index) {
        return [
            '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">',
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle userstable-button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">',
            '<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>',
            '<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>',
            '</button></div>'
            ].join('');
    }
```